# List of table which don't have a primary key

Tags: oracle

Need to get the list of tables name from a schema which doesn't have a primary key. I tried the following query to get this, but it will list all other keys except primary keys.

```
SELECT a.constraint_name,a.table_name
FROM ALL_CONS_COLUMNS A
JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS C
ON A.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE
C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE not in('P')
and a.owner ='my_schema';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want this for the current user, it's better to user the `user_xxx` views instead of the `all_xxx` views.

The following should do what you want:

```
select ut.table_name
from user_tables ut
where not exists (select 1
                  from user_constraints ac
                  where ac.table_name = ut.table_name
                    and ac.constraint_type = 'P'
                  );
```

If you do need this for a different user, then you can use the following.

```
select at.*
from all_tables at
where not exists (select 1
                  from all_constraints ac
                  where ac.owner = at.owner
                    and ac.table_name = at.table_name
                    and ac.constraint_type = 'P'
                  )
and at.owner = 'MY_SCHEMA';
```

Don't forget that Oracle is case sensitive and that user names are stored in uppercase, so `a.owner ='my_schema'` will most probably not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
select owner,table_name
from all_tables
where owner = 'my_schema' 
MINUS
select owner,table_name
from all_constraints
where owner = 'my_schema' 
and constraint_type = 'P'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM   all_tables A 
WHERE  table_name NOT IN 
     (
     SELECT table_name 
     FROM   all_constraints WHERE constraint_type ='P' 
     )
AND   a.owner = 'my_schema';
```

Answer (score 0):

Select     tables.owner || ‘.’ ||
tables.table_name
as   table_owner
From               all_tables      tables,
(Select
owner,
TABLE_NAME,
constraint_type,
CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = ‘P’     /* list of all tables with PK */
)  constr
Where              tables.owner = constr.owner (+)
And                tables.table_name = constr.table_name (+)
and   tables.owner <> ‘SYS’
and tables.owner <> ‘SYSTEM’
And                constr.owner IS NULL
And                constr.table_name IS NULL
ORDER BY 1